# Определить, какая кнопка была нажата

Tags: javascript

Есть три кнопки:

```
<button type='button'>1</button>
<button type='button'>2</button>
<button type='button'>3</button>
```

И код:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', detect);
});
const detect = () => {
  //
};
```

Как в функции detect определить, какая кнопка была нажата?
Пробовал через 
console.log(this), но это срабатывает только в функции внутри addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const detect = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
};
buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', detect);
});
```

```html
<button type='button'>1</button>
<button type='button'>2</button>
<button type='button'>3</button>
```

Comment: `e.target` - это может быть не совсем то, что хочет ТС, т.к. `target` - это элемент, на котором произошло событие, а не на который был повешен обработчик события.

Answer (score -1):

В событие доступна переменная `this`. В ней находится элемент на котором стоит обработчик и в случае срабатывания события он возвращает этот элемент.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
      detect = function(){
          console.log(this.innerHTML);
          console.log(this);
      };

 buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', detect);
 });
```

Comment: Сдается мне, ваш код не будет работать.